# Understanding Formula for the Pair Correlation for the Farey Sequence

Tags: number-theory, analysis, correlation

I'm reading this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404114.pdf, and I'm unsure how to interpret the formula in Theorem 2 (1.5), regarding the pair correlation function of the sequence of Farey Fractions. Specifically, I don't understand the $\lambda$ that they used.

In (1.6), they wrote as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$,  $g_2(λ) = 1 + O(λ^{−1})$. So this means the function approaches 1 as $\lambda$ goes to infinity. This seems reasonable as I could see the function asymptotically approaching 1, the problem is I'm not sure what $\lambda$ means in this context.

The only time they mentioned $\lambda$ beforehand is on page 2 when they defined

$R_F^{(v)}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{v-1})=2^{-v+1}R_F^{(v)}(\prod_{j=1}^{v-1}[-\lambda_j,\lambda_j]).$

My guess right now is that $\lambda$ refers to the interval for which the correlation measures are taken. Thus, as the interval of normalized Farey Fractions become arbitrarily large, the function converges to 1. Is that reasonable? Then $\lambda$ would represent a box in $\mathbb{R}^{v-1}$ for $v \geq3$.

Could someone give me some clarity on what this $\lambda$ represents and how this would change for $v\geq 3$? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a better idea not to look at the (free) parameter $\lambda$, but instead to look at $g_2$. On page 2, $g_2$ is defined as a function such that the $2$-level correlation measure is given by

$$ \mathcal{R}^{2}(\mathcal{B}) = \int_{\mathcal{B}} g_2(x_1) dx_1.$$

So $\lambda$ (in their Theorem 2) is just a number. I suppose they could have called it $x_1$, but that seems pretty odd.

Note that this is strongly analogous to the [pair correlation function for $\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture).

An analogous function for higher level correlation would necessarily be higher-dimensional. This is sometimes studied along with random-matrix theory, and called "$n$-level density". See for example [this preprint by Chandee and Lee](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02848).

Comment: Thank you, so to get this straight, $g_2(x_1)$ is a FUNCTION with respect to $x_1$, that can be inserted into the equation to $R^2(B)$ which takes this function and calculates the pair correlation MEASURE with respect to an interval $B$?

Comment: Yep. That's how this works. Ths $g_2$ here corresponds to $(1 - (\frac{\sin \pi \lambda}{\pi \lambda})^2)$, just a function of $\lambda$, in the case of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I had a question about how I could interpret this? Clearly, as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$, $g_2$ approaches 1. So, what does this tell us about the Farey Sequence?

Comment: That's a much more complicated question, since for Farey fractions the measure $\mathcal{R}$ itself is a bit of an annoying thing to think about. But if you can wrap your head around $\mathcal{R}$, then in some sense $g_2$ is like its derivative. Slightly more formally, choose intervals $\mathcal{B} = [0, t]$ and define the function $\mathcal{R}(t) = \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{B}) = \int_0^t g_2(x) dx$. Then the derivative of $\mathcal{R}(t)$ for large $t$ approaches $1$. What this really says is that the normalization chosen in the limit definition of $\mathcal{R}$ is the "right one" (cont...)

Comment: ... More locally, it says something like that the number of Farey fractions that are "far apart" from each other behaves roughly randomly. Again slightly more formally, it says something like the number of pairs of Farey fractions in a certain "far" distance behave like the number of pairs of uncorrelated random Poisson points. For more, I suggest studying what people have written about the pair correlation for the zeta function, as this is an easier object to understand. (Finally, welcome to MSE! If this answer was helpful to you, it is nice to upvote and/or mark it as accepted).

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your detailed responses, I accepted your answer. Now, if I wanted to calculate $g_3(\lambda_1,\lambda_2$), I would have to first calculate the 3-level correlation measure which they formulated in Theorem 1, and then solve for $g_3(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ by differentiating this measure, with respect to $B$ which would be in 3-dimensions, or something similar to this, right?